# How to append an element, then get the last child without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code working with jQuery, but how would I get the same functionality without using jQuery?

```
Sk.domOutput = function(html) {
    return jQuery('body').append(html).children().last();
};
```

You will find the whole code : https://plnkr.co/edit/93BU7m0A5qGJlosD8QQX?p=preview

Comment: what is `html`? a `HTMLElement` or a `String`?

Comment: the function is called like that : var $elem = Sk.domOutput('<div></div>');

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `html` is string of HTML, you can use:

1. Create a new `HTMLElement` with `createElement()`:

   ```
   let el = document.createElement('div');`
   ```
2. Then add the html inside the `div` by changing the `innerHTML` property:

   ```
   el.innerHTML = html;
   ```

   At this point, you have your HTML wrapped inside `div` tags.
3. Append the first child of the created element to the `body` of the document to only append the inside of the `div`:

   ```
   document.querySelector('body').appendChild(el.firstChild)
   ```
4. Lastly, return the newly added element:

   ```
   return el
   ```

So the final code is:

```
Sk.domOutput = function(html) {
   let el = document.createElement('div');
   el.innerHTML = html;
   document.querySelector('body').appendChild(el.firstChild)
   return el
};
```

Comment: @Julien, can you give us more information so we can help you?

Comment: You will find the whole code : https://plnkr.co/edit/93BU7m0A5qGJlosD8QQX?p=preview